# Postfix setup issue

Tags: postfix

I'm trying to allow an external server to use my webserver (running postfix) to relay email through. I've gone through several articles on setting up iptables and I think I have it, but I still can't get email to flow. I can't do a telnet to port 25 on the webserver either. Below is my iptables. Anyone see anything I missed?

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG -j DROP
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s X.X.X.X/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s X.X.X.X/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 20 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 123 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 3):

By default `postfix` is set to listen on `127.0.0.1` in most distro's

1. open `/etc/postfix/main.cf`
2. Look for a group of lines that start with  `inet_interfaces`

You might see the one uncommented like

```
inet_interfaces = localhost
```

That means its only listening on localhost or 127.0.0.1. Change it to

```
inet_interfaces = all
```

Then restart `postfix` and it should work.

Comment: OK, I did that, however I still can't telnet to it from the outside. It works internally, but not from the outside. Any other ideas?

Comment: Wait a second, I just did a test from mxtoolbox.com and its now responding. Looks like I have some troubleshooting to do on my pc now.